# Difference between 'la frutta' and 'i frutti'

Tags: difference, meaning

Besides the fact that 'i frutti' can assume a metaphoric meaning which 'la frutta' does not have, is there any other difference between these two wordings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Besides the metaphoric meaning you already mentioned (that is widely used), in gereral *frutta* refers to a type of food, whereas *frutti* indicates multiple *pieces of fruit* grouped according to some criterion, usually the fact that they come from a given plant. For instance, you say *i frutti di quell'albero sono molto dolci* ("the fruits of that tree are very sweat"), and *la frutta è un alimento sano* ("fruit is healthy"). As usual, handle with care: you may be tempted to say *porta i frutti* to mean "bring the fruit", but you should use *frutta* instead. There are grey areas: *i frutti più buoni sono quelli appena colti* and *la frutta più buona è quella appena colta* sound both fine to me, but YMMV and regionalisms may kick in of course.

Comment: It is yet again one of those words with a double plural, like "osso" , and the difference between the two plurals follows the same rule. There was a question about this but I can't find it any more.

Comment: To complement the remark by @writingthesis, keep in mind that *frutta* used to be a plural form of *frutto* (*le frutta*). As for some other double plurals (*le membra* / *i membri*, *le budella* / *i budelli* etc.) the “neuter” one (the one in -*a*) refers to a generic set of similar things, while the masculine one (in -*i*) refers to several distinct items.